# Could a goliath grapple huge creatures because of his Powerful Build?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, racial-traits

Goliaths have feature **Powerful Build**, which says

> **Powerful Build.** You count as one size larger when determining your carrying capacity and the weight you can push, drag, or lift.

Does it mean that they are able to grapple huge creatures normally?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: "[Can an enlarged Goliath grapple without movement penalty?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88431)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

> You count as one size larger **when determining your carrying capacity and the weight you can push, drag, or lift**

Grappling is defined as a Special type of Melee Attack that can be used to replace one of your Attacks as part of the Attack action.

> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach.

RAW, this is unaffected by the Powerful Build feature.